# how to zip stream csv file php

Tags: php, csv, php-ziparchive, zipstream

I created an .csv export file with code:

```
header('Content-type: text.csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename.csv');
.....
$fp = fopen('php://output','w');
foreach ($rowsCsv as $rowCsv) {
    fwrite($fp, $rowCsv);
}
fclose($fp);
```

It work ok but I want to compress the csv file to zip file and download it. How do it

Comment: Isn't it `Content-type: text/csv`? Also, look for the PHP zip extensions.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php

Answer (score 4):

You should read a CSV file before exported, or you only need put `filename.csv` into file:

```
$file_folder = "folder_you_stored/";    // change folder
$file = "filename.csv";                 // your CSV filename from exported done

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = "archiver.zip";

    $string_data = 'dumped data of CSV';

$zip->addFile($file_folder.$file); // store a file OR below
$zip->addString("your_filename.csv", $string_data); // file store of string data

# download action
header('Content-type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($string_data));
readfile($zip_name);
unlink($zip_name);
```

PHP.NET reference how to using ZIP archive: http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.phpž

Put instead of `addFile` add as string as example:

```
$fp = fopen('php://output','w');
foreach ($rowsCsv as $rowCsv) {
    $zip->addFromString('example.csv', $rowCsv);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to add .csv file without creating a temporary file on disk

Comment: You need first CSV file read a data and save CSV file to folder and read CSV filename to put into ZIP.

Comment: I've update answer. You need put all strings data into string addString('file.csv', 'your csv strings data readed or outputed for CSV');